# How do I relate recursion to the remainder operator?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm using Eloquent JavaScript to learn JavaScript. I am a beginner and I would like to understand how this exercise works, it is about recursion and relating in to the remainder operator. I don't understand the comparison and I really would love to know how it works.

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n == 0) return true;
  else if (n == 1) return false;
  else if (n < 0) return isEven(-n);
  else return isEven(n - 2);
}
console.log(isEven(50)) //true;
console.log(isEven(75)) //false;
console.log(isEven(-1)) //false;
```

I tried testing **-2** in the log and it prints **true**, why does it do that?

I don't fully understand recursion or JavaScript that much, I would like it if this example is explained to me like I am 5.

Comment: ?? The remainder operator is not used in the code you posted. Also `-2` is an even number.

Comment: um because `else if (n < 0) return isEven(-n);`

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/quick-intro-to-recursion/#:~:text=Recursion%20is%20when%20a%20function,unit%20of%20work%20multiple%20times.

Comment: Do you understand what [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) is? Your function takes advantage of the fact that for any even number, if you keep subtracting 2 from it,  it will eventually become zero. When that happens, base case of `if (n == 0)` evaluates to true and as a result, true is returned by the function. For any odd number, subtracting two from it will eventually give you the value 1, which makes the second base case `if (n == 1)` to evaluate to true, as a result false is returned.

Comment: @epascarello yes i see that but what does it mean? what does it do?

Comment: @Yousaf i understand now, especially the part of the code where it keeps on subtracting 2 from the number i give it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Labeling the different decisions:

```
function isEven (n) {
    if (n == 0) return true; // 1
    else if (n == 1) return false; // 2
    else if (n < 0) return isEven(-n); // 3
    else return isEven(n - 2); // 4
}
```

when you call `isEven(-2)` it then calls `isEven(2)` according to `// 3` which then calls calls `isEven(0)` according to `// 4` which then returns `true` according to `// 1`

Comment: i wont lie but you just made me even more confused, can you explain this to me like i am 5?